# Netbeans 18 and spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, netbeans

I have problems using the internal servers from spring-boot framework in Netbeans 18. I have generated simple spring-boot project using generator from https://start.spring.io/.
The project has the following configuration: java language, Maven, Spring Boot 3.2.0, war packaging, Java 20, Spring Web dependency.

I have JDK 20 installed in windows 11.

When trying to run the project, I don't select any local server.

Netbeans says that there is no server configuration on main project. I have a lot of plugins installed in Netbeans (only those that I had needed).

How can I make Netbean 18 to see the internal spring-boot server configuration?

using internal spring-boot server (tomcat) with Netbean 18

Comment: is this specific to netbeans or does the project has same issue on another ide like eclipse too ?

Comment: I didn't tested with other IDE's

Comment: with eclipse worked the connection to oracle database, on netbeans didn't

Comment: Currently, I'm using it in a project, NetBeans 18 with Spring Boot and with Maven. We had some difficulties, but we are managing to make progress on the project. The packaging is war. To run/debug the project, we use the run/debug file feature, for the file with the main class, annotated with @SpringBootApplication. We have not configured/selected any servers for the project. The Spring team should develop a version of the STS (Spring Tools Suite) for NetBeans.

Comment: you can also right click the project node, click properties, then Run, then set the main class.  This will let you push the run button without error.